# Square free integers

Tags: number-theory

Let $Q(n)$ denote the number of square free integers $\le n$. It is easy to show that
$$Q(n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}n+O(n^{1/2})$$
However Wikipedia also tells me that 
$$Q(n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}n+O(n^{1/2-\epsilon})$$
For some positive $\epsilon$. (It actually states a stronger result, but I am only interested in the above equation). I would like to know if anyone can give link to a paper, or source of information proving the above result. If they can think of a way to prove it themselves, they are more than welcome. I am specifically interested in seeing whether this equation can be proved $without$ the PNT and hopefully without to much complex analysis. Given that the actual estimate is 
$$Q(n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}n+O(n^{0.315+\epsilon})$$
I am hoping it isn't too tircky to prove my lesser estimate. I have had a change of heart here. From what I am reading online atm, it may be "extremely hard to improve" on the original estimate.

Comment: In fact $Q(n)=\frac6/\pi^2 x+o(x^{1/2})$ is already equivalent (I think) to the PNT; see e.g. http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/ant/ exercise 3.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the proof of $Q(n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}+O(\sqrt{n})$ is elementary (see [here](http://web2.mat.uniroma3.it/users/pappa/papers/allahabad2003.pdf)) , it seems that any improvement on the exponent $n^{1/2}$ uses already non-trivial results on zero-free regions for the Riemann zeta function, like the proof of PNT does. This has been done in Walfisz, A. Weylsche Exponentialsummen in der neueren Zahlentheorie, using the classical zero–free region estimates due to Vinogradov and Korobov through exponential sums. 
Most papers improve the exponent by assuming already the Riemann hypothesis. Then (assuming RH) we obtain
$$
Q(n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}+O(n^{\frac{17}{54}+\epsilon}),
$$
by a result of Jia in $1993$.

Comment: I suspect that improving on the $O(x^{1/2})$ bound may be actually equivalent to the PNT, so not an easy task it seems :(

Comment: The current best estimate is $$Q \left({n}\right) = \frac{6}{{\pi}^{2}} + O \left({{n}^{11/35 + \epsilon}}\right)$$ from Liu, H.-Q. (2016). "On the distribution of squarefree numbers". Journal of Number Theory. 159: 202–222. doi:10.1016/j.jnt.2015.07.013.